# How can a static object access non-static fields even though it's defined as static?

Tags: java, static

How can a static object access non-static fields even though it's defined as static?

```
public class pp {
    static int x = 4;
    int y = 8;
    public static pp hj = new pp();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hj.y); //prints 8
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are getting `y` from an instance (namely `hj`).

Comment: It works as done on getting non static method in static method thru instances....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a non-static member, such as `y`, from static context, such as `main`, as long as you have a *static* instance from which you are accessing the non-static member.

In your case, `hj` is a static instance. It can be accessed from static context, along with `y`, which is its non-static field.

In contrast, if you were to attempt accessing `y` in static context *without* an object reference, your code would fail to compile:

```
public class pp {
    static int x = 4;
    int y = 8;
    static int z = y + 5; // <<=== This does not compile

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(y); // <<=== This does not compile either
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hj` is a `static` field of the `pp` class yes. But it refers also an instance of `pp`.

So you can use `hj` to access to any instance member (method or field) of the `pp` class.

But if you try to access to the instance field :

```
int y = 8;
```

from the `static main method()` in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

you will see that you cannot as a `static` member cannot refer to an instance member.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static pp hj = new pp();
```

> How can a static object access non-static fields even though it's defined as static?

Here just the reference to the object is static which means that to access that varaible (`hj`) you need not to create an object of it's owner.

Once you got the reference to the object  you can access the object members though it is static or non static reference.